# Create an array of timestamps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I have been trying to create a time vector in `python 3.x` to plot wind velocity against time.
Wind Velocity was sampled every 5 minutes, starting from 00:00 and finishing at 23:55 (i.e., 288 samples per day).

I use `pandas` to read the data. I store velocity variables in a `numpy` vector. I saved variables using `numpy.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'm/s Wind'])` and work perfect for wind speed. When I tried to do it for `datetime` variables, as `numpy.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'Measurement Time'])` showed me the next error:

`'the label [Measurement Time] is not in the [columns]'` (please see code behind for more detail)

`met1.head()` looks like this:

```
 .                  m/s Wind  m/s Gusts  ° Direction        RH  °C Temp  \
Measurement Time                                                           
2018-11-13 11:20:00      6.77        9.5          268  0.068590     12.6   
2018-11-13 11:25:00      6.90       10.4          284  0.067255     12.9   
2018-11-13 11:30:00      6.59       11.3          279  0.066381     13.1   
2018-11-13 11:35:00      7.10       10.1          279  0.073019     13.1   
2018-11-13 11:40:00      6.01        9.8          273  0.073498     13.0
```

Code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

met1 = pd.read_excel('database.xls', sheet_name=0, skiprows=2, index_col = 'Measurement Time', parse_dates=[0]) #reading data base

def variables (ini, fin):
# Variables for MET-1
    wind1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'm/s Wind'])
    dir1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, '° Direction'])
    rh1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'RH']) # 0.123
    temp1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, '°C Temp'])
    p1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'kPa Pressure'])
    tiempo = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'Measurement Time'])
    print(wind1)
    print(tiempo)

variables('2018-11-15','2018-11-15')
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1789                 if not ax.contains(key):
-> 1790                     error()
   1791             except TypeError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in error()
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 

KeyError: 'the label [Measurement Time] is not in the [columns]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-130dc8c7095b> in <module>
      1 # variables('2018-11-13','2018-11-13') # Mount day
      2 # variables('2018-11-14','2018-11-14') # Mount day
----> 3 variables('2018-11-15','2018-11-15')
      4 variables('2018-11-16','2018-11-16')
      5 variables('2018-11-17','2018-11-17')

<ipython-input-181-2a7e1e919435> in variables(ini, fin)
     17     temp1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, '°C Temp'])
     18     p1 = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'kPa Pressure'])
---> 19     tiempo = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'Measurement Time'])
     20     print(tiempo)
     21 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1470             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1471                 pass
-> 1472             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1473         else:
   1474             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    868     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    869         try:
--> 870             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    871         except IndexingError:
    872             pass

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    996         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    997             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 998                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    999 
   1000                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1909 
   1910         # fall thru to straight lookup
-> 1911         self._validate_key(key, axis)
   1912         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1913 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1796                 raise
   1797             except:
-> 1798                 error()
   1799 
   1800     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in error()
   1783                 raise KeyError(u"the label [{key}] is not in the [{axis}]"
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 
   1787             try:

KeyError: 'the label [Measurement Time] is not in the [columns]'
```

**The time vector I need should look like this!!!:** `['00:00' '00:05' ..... '23:50' '23:55']` for date `'2018-11-15'`

Comment: please provide the sample data for your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add the head of the database. I tried to save the variable as `tiempo = np.array(met1.loc[ini:fin, 'Measurement Time'])` but   when I `print(tiempo)` show me the next error: `'the label [Measurement Time] is not in the [columns]'`

Comment: And what isn't working, exactly?

Comment: If you store measurement time in Python strings, you can just crop them with slices: `datetime = datetime[:-3]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  When I `print(wind1)` returns `numpy` vector with magnitud velocities for 2018-11-15. Maybe `index_col` when importing database is making this problem but if i change `index_col` all my code will not work. So I dont know how to create a time vector in order to plot wind velocity (`wind1`) vs time in `HH:MM` format

Comment: *Edit your question don't put this in the comments*. Show us, **exactly** the output you are seeing and provide an example of the output you require.

Comment: all right! Gracias @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: You've made the 'Measurement Time' column your index, you cannot use it like a column anymore. Try just `met1.loc[ini:fin].index.values`